# Can't Install Steam

Tags: steam

I'm running into a problem on a new Ubuntu install with Steam. It says I have missing packages when I issue the "install steam" command below.

```
user@test-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when I try and get some of the missing packages, it shows I am dependant on even more packages, as shown below.

```
user@test-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is     not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it     is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I must be doing something wrong here. Can someone advise me what to do please?

FYI I have also performed the following commands with no joy:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

As per suggestions, I have also tried:

```
user@test-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another     package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Why not just install Steam from their website?

Comment: On many of my posts in the past, people say it's better to not do that because updating in the future may be a problem. I don't understand it enough, so I just trust them, and try to get my packages/dependencies through apt.

Comment: I can tell you that Steam updates itself perfectly fine from using the download. Normally, I recommend using the Software Center or terminal over downloads, but that's mostly when the download is just the source and needs to be compiled. Just try the installation from the site. It might also fail, but it'll be something if it works. If you want to keep with the apt method, try running `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then try again.

Comment: software center doesn't work mate. I want it to install properly, not just install it from the website.

Comment: The Software Center and terminal method are exactly the same. Try the command.

Comment: But there is missing dependencies. I can't understand why you want me to force an install that is missing dependencies? It seems like it would just be a bodge.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` means `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`. It fixes missing dependencies. It's a standalone command.

Comment: Again the same problem with -f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Canonical Partner Repository.

Open **Software and Updates** and under **Other Software** tab enable Canonical Partners.

Select "Close" and "Reload"

Finally,

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Comment: Updating my main post

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version you're on?

Comment: It is 14.04 trusty

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386`

Comment: When I input that command I get:    E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid. And if I try to install this extra package, I get another bunch of dependencies that I'm missing

Comment: On your modified comment I get lots more missing dependancies

Comment: Open software updates and under **Ubuntu Software tab** tick everything. Then under **Other Software** tab enable Canonical Partners. And in the `Updates` tab enable recommended updates. Then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31599/discussion-between-john-smith-and-reversiblean).

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04, this will work: sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 and
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386